# How to change default culture to fr-FR instead of en-US?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, .net-7.0

I want to change default culture to 'fr-FR'.
I use this code in program.cs but 'en-us' is default culture.
please help me to resolve it.

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),

    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "fr-FR", uiCulture: "fr-FR");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
});

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRequestLocalization(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapRazorPages();
    
    app.Run();
```

this code is ignored:

```
options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "fr-FR", uiCulture: "fr-FR");
```

Comment: "this code is ignored:" -  how do you check that?

Comment: with 'Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name' in OnGet() method. it is 'en-US'.

Comment: And how do you get to `OnGet` method? Do you submit request from browser?

Comment: Yes.I run the project. for the first time that page is loaded it is 'en-US'.

Comment: Check out the network tab. I'm pretty much sure that you will see the something like `Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,da;q=0.7` send by the browser. Make request from postman without `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: Yes in network tab in Request header, 'Accept-Language:' is 'en-US,en;q=0.9' and with postman without Accept-Language I get 'fr-FR'. what should I do?

Comment: Nothing. Your code works just fine. The culture is determined by browser. You can change the default culture in your browser or (again) use some tool which will not send the header.

Comment: But I want the end user see my website with 'fr-FR' culture by default. Because my default language is french.

Comment: This is a bit more complex topic. How user will switch the language? _"Because my default language is french."_  - and user's =) ?

Comment: I have two buttons for english and french. and I use 'asp-route-culture="en-US" for english and 'asp-route-culture="fr-FR"' for french.

Comment: Try changing code to `options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear(); options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());` instead of inserting.

Comment: My default culture changed to 'fr-FR'. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup works as expected. `"en-US"` is allowed culture and by default one of the providers is `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider` which will check for the `Accept-Language` header. And since this header is send by default by your browser (with value `"en-US"` or something like this) it's value will be used to set appropriate culture for the request handler. If you don't want this header to affect the selected culture you can remove it. For example by completely clearing `RequestCultureProviders`:

```
options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear(); 
// and add the one you are want
options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
```